# java generate and check creditcard

Tags: java

i need to make something in java that generates random card number and checks if its valid or not.
this is the code we all must have in main

```
public enum CardType { VISA, MASTER, AMERICAN_EXPRESS, DISCOVERY }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CardType type = CardType.VISA;
String cardNumber = generateCardNumber(type);
    System.out.println("Generated " + type + " number " + cardNumber + " validity check: "  + isValid(cardNumber));
    type = CardType.MASTER;
cardNumber = generateCardNumber(type);
System.out.println("Generated " + type + " number " + cardNumber + " validity check: " + isValid(cardNumber));
  }
```

and now i need to use this method.but how can i make it (CardType type = CardType.VISA;) work ? 
what do i need to return ?
a little help will save my life :)

```
public static String generateCardNumber(CardType cardType){
Random rnd = new Random();
int counter=0;
while(counter<=16){
int generate = rnd.nextInt(9); 
counter++;
}
return ??;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you need to return a String the represents the credit card number. Since we have no knowledge about your CardTypes and their requirements for a valid number, it will be hard to help you unless you tell and show more. Assume that we can't read minds and that we can't understand code not shown, and you'll understand our predicament.

Comment: You don't need to generate all the numbers since the first few digits depend on the [issuer identification numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Issuer_Identification_Numbers). This tells you the first numbers you can use for every credit card type.

Comment: Um, I guess my comment was written in invisible ink. I'll have to check my keyboard to make sure it's not at fault.

Answer (score 4):

You can use abstract methods in an enum and use that to generate a known valid card number:

```
public enum CardType
{
    VISA {
        @Override
        public String generateNumber()
        {
            // whatever
        }
    },
    // Other card types

    public abstract String generateNumber();
}
```

This way, you can do:

```
final String cardNumber = CardType.VISA.generateNumber();
```

and not bother checking for the validity of the generted number *afterwards*, since you can ensure that it is valid within the method itself.

Comment: uh interesting, i didn't know enums can contain abstract methods.

Comment: I didn't know it either until I read Josch Bloch's 2nd edition of "Effective Java" ;) This book is a gold mine and, imho, a must have.

Comment: interesting indeed, though I believe OP was asking for what you marked as "whatever".

Comment: @Oren: the consistency check can be done within the `generateNumber()` method itself. And you have all of Java's mechanisms at your disposal for this method, it needs not be totally enclosed within the enum.

Comment: static boolean isValid(String cardNumber): returns whether a 16 digit card number is valid or not [how can i do that with math calculations ? not luhn ]Double every second digit from right to left. If doubling of a digit results in a two-digit number, add up the two 
digits to get a single-digit number.

Comment: @user1925151 do you mean this validation function is valid for whatever card type you generate? Have a link to the algorithm? If this is the same for each card type, you can even embody the check within the enum itself.

Comment: http://pdfcast.org/pdf/hw-8 this is the document bro

Comment: is it clear to understand ?

Comment: @user1925151 this is clear enough, do you have an implementation for that already?

Comment: I'll bet @user1925151 is asking for the implementation code, but who knows since he refuses to clarify the question per my comments at the top. -1 to his question til he does.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what your question is, however. To resolve one error I see in the code I would assign generate to a string each time. Something like;

```
public static String generateCardNumber(CardType cardType){
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int counter=0;
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    while(counter<=16){
        int generate = rnd.nextInt(9); 
        stringBuffer.append(generate);
        counter++;
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

Then validating that the String is a card will require another step based on your requirements.

Comment: so where can i start to do that?  Generated VISA number 4851936596972692 validity check: true
Generated MASTER number 5746910961957642 validity check: true

Comment: Do what? Assuming you mean card validation... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895535/validate-credit-card-details

Comment: i need to check with luhn yes but the harder way unfortunetly :(   static int getSumOfOddDigits(String number) i mean i gotta do the calculatinos (math)